# Cannot generate components via Angular CLI after Upgrade to V15.1.2

Tags: angular, angular-cli

My team recently upgraded a project to Angular V15.1.2 and since then I've not been able to run simple cli commands such as `ng g c components/test`. I'm not having the same issue in my other project that is running Angular 15.0.1, so at least that should rule out an error with my version of NPM or Node. The following is the error that I receive:

> An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot destructure property 'aliases' of 'collection.description.schematics[schematicName]' as it is undefined.
> See "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-4fyV7s\angular-errors.log" for further details.

The following is the further details mentioned above:

> [error] TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'aliases' of 'collection.description.schematics[schematicName]' as it is undefined.
> at GenerateCommandModule.getSchematics (C:\Projects\GitHub\app\node_modules@angular\cli\src\commands\generate\cli.js:141:29)
> at getSchematics.next ()
> at GenerateCommandModule.getSchematicsToRegister (C:\Projects\GitHub\pau-pe-shutdownreporting\shutdown-app\node_modules@angular\cli\src\commands\generate\cli.js:158:76)
> at async GenerateCommandModule.builder (C:\Projects\GitHub\app\node_modules@angular\cli\src\commands\generate\cli.js:35:55)
> at async runCommand (C:\Projects\GitHub\app\node_modules@angular\cli\src\command-builder\command-runner.js:113:5)
> at async default_1 (C:\Projects\GitHub\app\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js:70:16)

This is on a Windows 10 machine within a Git Bash terminal within VSCode. Others on my team are also having the same issue, so it may be something with the project setup after the upgrade.

Comment: I am having the same issue after upgrading to angular 15.1.1.

Comment: I fixed my issue by updating to 15.1.3

Comment: As @BrightDodo mentioned - `@angular/cli` 15.1.3 fixes https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/24586.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently my issue was caused by some issues while the project was being upgraded that caused the angular packages to not all be upgraded correctly. If you are running into this issue, check that @angular/compiler-cli has been upgraded to the same level as @angular/cli.

Comment: how did you fix it?

Comment: @softwareisfun, I just had to change the version of @angular/compiler-cli in the package.json to match the version of @angular/cli and install npm packages.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was having the same problem today, I fixed with:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest


npm install
ng g c components/test
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, the cause was that ng cli local and global were different versions

```
Your global Angular CLI version (15.2.5) is greater than your local version (15.1.2). The local Angular CLI version is used.
```

Solution: Uninstalled the local ng cli and reinstalling latest fixed the issue.

```
> npm uninstall  @angular/cli
> npm install  @angular/cli@latest
```